# How to parse a JSON when the property's name is different

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, c#-4.0, serialization

I'm using ***System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer***, is there any whay that I can 'cast' the property's name to parse JSON to my object? For example:
Case 1: This is my JSON:

> {"o":{"name" : "Tom", "age" : 22}}

Case 2:

> {"o":{"nickname" : "Tom", "age" : 22}}

and here is my class:

```
class Test {
  public string name {get; set; }
  public int age {get; set; }
}
class MyObj {
  public Test data {get; set; }
}
```

Can any way to parse both of the JSON string in case 1 and case 2 to the instance of MyObj?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to do a search and replace on the returned JSON string, and replace "nickname" with "name" although that's not exactly elegant.